# Why are the variables inside my Vue method not updating based on the v-click directive I have set on multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

v-on:click="removeProduct" is not updating variables I'm setting inside the removeProduct function inside the methods object. Specifically, the unique product key set on each table row should be getting stored inside a variable with the help of jQuery, then updated each time the function fires.

When the  tag is initially clicked, it removes the closest tr from the DOM.  When the  tag is then clicked again, the product is only successfully removed if the tr's index has not already been clicked. i.e, I successfully remove the first row from the table, then the second row becomes the first. I cannot remove the new first row, only the new second row.

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(part) in parts" v-bind:data-product-key="part.productKey">
        <td>{{ part.productCategoryTitle }}</td>
        <td>{{ part.productName }}</td>
        <td>{{ part.productSKU }}</td>
        <td><input type="number" @focus="storeInitialQuantity" @blur="updateQuantity" min="0" step="1" v-bind:value="part.productQuantity"></td>
        <td><i class="fas fa-times-circle text-danger fa-2x" v-bind:data-product-key="part.productKey" v-on:click="removeProduct"></i></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
window.vmOrderForm = new Vue({
    el: '#v-order-data',
    data: {
        parts: [],
    },
    methods: {
        removeProduct: function( event ) {
            let _this = this,
                tableRow = $( event.target ).closest( 'tr' ),
                productKey = tableRow.data( 'product-key' );

            console.log( productKey );

            tableRow.addClass( 'removing' );

            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxObject.ajaxUrl,
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    action: 'get_order_data',
                    productKey: productKey,
                    quantity: 0,
                },
                success: function( response ) {
                    _this.parts = response.data;
                },
                complete: function() {
                    tableRow.removeClass( 'removing' );
                },
            });
        },
    }
});
```

Since there are many  elements in the table, each with their own unique product key set in their data-attribute, every time an  tag is clicked, the function should fire and grab the data attribute value of the closest . Is Vue somehow indexing the rows of my table and since I'm updating the DOM, doesn't know to update the variables in my method?

Comment: Not a solution but why not just pass `part.productKey` to your `removeProduct` method directly instead of pulling it from the `<tr>` `data-product-key` attribute? Ie, `@click="removeProduct(part.productKey)"` and `removeProduct: function(productKey) { ... }`

Comment: As for a solution, try adding `:key="part.productKey"` to your `<tr>`

Comment: The duplicates I've linked at the top of your question should help but if they don't, let me know and I'll re-open your question.

Comment: @Phil this is absolutely brilliant, thank you so much.

Comment: @Phil Bonus questions if you don't mind. Why do you and why can you omit "v-bind" from ":key"? I notice the Vue docs don't omit it: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Comment: @Phil Also, why don't I have to pass 'event' in as a parameter but can still access it in my function?

Comment: 1) See [Template Syntax - Shorthands](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands). 2) Your browser is providing a global `event` variable. As with most globals, it's not good to rely on this.